# Creating a sentence from excel data

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a spreadsheet with the following headings: apples, oranges, bananas, pears and peaches.  They are all headings for a list of different farmers.  Under these headings it either says yes or is blank indicating if the farmer has these fruits on hand or not.

I am trying to create a sentence for each farmer that adds the heading titles to a sentence based on this data for each fruit type, skipping over the field if it doesn’t have the fruit on hand.  If the farmer had 5 fruits, the sentence would be “The farmer has apples, oranges, bananas, pears and peaches.”

I have tried the following IF statement but it isn’t working: 
 ="The farmer has "&IF(A2="yes",IF(B2="yes",A1&", "&B1,IF(C2="yes",A1&", "&B1&", "&C1)))

It works fine up until I add the third fruit, when I put “yes” in C2 nothing happens, but if i remove the yes in B2 then the full sentence as per the equation works.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  My second question is how many fruits would I be limited to using this approach?  And if it is limited, is there another approach that permits more fruit types?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The formula is not correct because you put the condition C2 = "yes" in else statement of B2 = "yes"

Your formula

```
="The farmer has " &
IF(
    A2 = "yes", 
    IF(
        B2 = "yes",
        A1 & ", " & B1,
        ---
        IF(
            C2 = "yes",
            A1 & ", " & B1 & ", " & C1
        )
        ---
    )
)
```

You could do like this

```
="The farmer has " &
IF(
    A2 = "yes",
    A1,
    ""
) & " " &
IF(
    B2 = "yes",
    B1,
    ""
) & " " &
IF(
    C2 = "yes",
    C1,
    ""
)
```

> My second question is how many fruits would I be limited to using this
>   approach? And if it is limited, is there another approach that permits
>   more fruit types?

Your approach is fine but it will make mistake because you need to care many many nested if-else state base on total fruit. You could try my approach

p/s sorry my English is not good

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  I've modified it slightly to include commas "," and the word "and".  ="The farmer has " &IF(A2 = "yes",A1," ") & ", " &IF(B2 = "yes",B1," ") & " and " &IF(C2 = "yes",C1," ") & "."
The resulting sentence is "The farmer has apples, oranges and bananas.”
The issue I’m having is when the third heading (bananas) is left blank.  The sentence then reads: “The farmer has apples, oranges and  .”  It should read: “The farmer has apples and oranges.”  Basically, I need to be able to control how and where the “,” “and” and “.” are located.

Comment: @user9488983 I'm not master in excel formula but I don't think you can do it with formula in excel. You can try to write Excel Marco, this will provide more way to satisfied your requirement